# Colored inorganic liquids: why is SCl2 red, and S2Cl2 orange?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, color, liquids

Those do not involve d orbitals, so there is no crystal field theory or ligand theory. Do we have a name of study that only involves p orbitals? Since I think molecular theory is for all s p d f orbitals and transitions.

Comment: According to ChatGPT, is due to leaving 2 unpaired electrons in an antibonding orbital, the interaction between these unpaired electrons causes a splitting of the energy levels, resulting in the absorption and reflection of light.

Comment: If you feel you have been personally affronted on the site you can use flags or send a message to a community or SE mod so that we can intervene as necessary. It is not usually useful to start a confrontation.

Comment: I am deleting your comments on this post as they are not about chemistry. You may start a chat with Poutnik about the meaning of the term "anti-Stokes", but please avoid unnecessary personal arguments.

Comment: Also, please note that ChatGPT has a very bad reputation as an unreliable source of information.

Comment: Maybe a reader invested in quantum chemistry can perform a computation to estimate which electronic transitions were plausible (and their corresponding gap).

Comment: @Buttonwood damn, I thought this was a question for inorganic experts. Thank you for letting me know that this is really a question for quantum chemists.

Comment: @Buttonwood when you said "Maybe a reader invested in quantum chemistry can perform a computation to estimate which electronic transitions were plausible" does that mean this question was not answerable before the age of computers? How would a computer program be able to solve this question?

Comment: @NealConroy In [H2S2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_disulfide), the S-S bond is 2.06 A, in [S2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disulfur) the S=S bond 1.89 A.  For [S2Cl2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disulfur_dichloride), the S-S distance is 1.95 A, as if there were a little bit of double bond character. Perhaps this is a contribution. For elements of the second period (after Ne), the empiric octet rule does not apply as strictly as on elements up to and including Ne, see e.g. [DMSO](http://www.chem.ucla.edu/~harding/IGOC/D/dmso.html). Others with said background likely know better.

Comment: @Buttonwood oh, so the computational chemistry is to calculate the bond-distance part?

Comment: @NealConroy Rather the other way around. The distance Wikipedia reports can be a result of a X-ray / neutron diffraction experiment, microwave spectroscopy, or ... what else. This distance to be shorter than the S-S single bond could be indicative for a small contribution by d orbitals. It is more common for folks in quantum chem than org chem to recognize if such an extension to describe the bonding in S2Cl2 with this additional contribution is significantly better; they can perform the relevant computations (at different levels of theory) and compare the results with data from experiments.

Comment: @Buttonwood so you said the S-S single bond is more closer in length to the S=S double bond, indicating a small contribution of d orbitals. Okay now look at my very 1st comment-reply at the top, where I pasted what ChatGPT said, you think what it said could be plausible? ;0

Comment: @NealConroy As stated, this enters territory beyond my knowledge, where referral to others who actually are in the field / possibly in the know is the best I can do for now. And I mark the question as «follow» to be notified if there is any advance in future by an answer by an other subscriber.