# Color change in coordination compounds

Tags: crystal-field-theory

When $\ce{FeCl3}$ is added in water it gives a pale yellow color, but on the addition of $\ce{KSCN}$ it changes to intense red color, so how would we explain the color change?

What I thought that the intensity would for sure change as when $\ce{FeCl3}$ is added with $\ce{KSCN}$ it would form a tetrahedral complex because $\ce{SCN^-}$ acts as a very weak field ligand, and as tetrahedral does not have center of symmetry La Porte Rule cannot be applied while in water it would form octahedral complex and on drawing the electronic configurations La Porte Rule will fail there, thus I came to the conclusion that color of the $\ce{KSCN}$ on would be more intense.

But how would we tell about the color change?

Comment: If someone is downvoting my post, would they at least tell me why are they doing so, I don't know all my previous posts were also heavily downvoted, and it only happens on chemistry stack exchange, on physics and math people do reply properly.

Comment: For future reference: for the body of questions, answers, and comments, chemistry.se offers to use [mhchem](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/) as a comfortable method to add chemical equations.

Comment: @KutubkhanBhatiya "all my previous posts" -> there is only one other post and that was closed as HW. Perhaps, you can edit the question and clarify so it can get opened. Downvoters are not obligated to give an explanation. (I am not the downvoter btw)

Comment: @NilayGhosh I am not trying to offend someone, but I deleted my previous posts as they were all closed due to downvotes

Comment: @NilayGhosh And I also changed the questions by following the guidelines they attached about the homework question and I followed it as well but then too it didn't get open, so that's why

Comment: @KutubkhanBhatiya that also is not a right approach. Deleting questions frequently because you receive downvotes might get you a question ban. Instead edit the posts.

Comment: @NilayGhosh I think Kutubkhan was right to delete his downvoted threads. I never deleted my threads and eventually got permanently banned by low score. They shut down most of my threads just saying "not focused enough" yet they weren't homework questions. SE had to delete my questions in order to remove my permanent ban...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The choice of «intensity» is not a good one here, because the change from (pale) yellow to red relates to different positions of the absorption band(s)  in terms of an energy split between orbitals / eventually recorded absorption wavelengths.

Second, in aqueous solutions $\ce{Fe^{3+}}$ *typically* is said to be an hexaaqua cation.  The *overall* reaction in aqueous solution hence is better described as

$$\ce{[Fe(H2O)6]^{3+} + 3 SCN^- <=> [Fe(SCN)3(H2O)3] + 3 H2O}$$

However, the situation is a bit more complex (literally) because exchange of water by $\ce{SCN^-}$ is *stepwise*.  This is to say that upon addition of the aqueous solution of $\ce{KSCN}$ you *simultaneously* have the equilibria of

$$\ce{[Fe(H2O)6]^{3+} + SCN^- <=> [Fe(SCN)(H2O)5]^{2+} + H2O}$$

and

$$\ce{[Fe(SCN)(H2O)5]^{2+} + SCN^- <=> [Fe(SCN)2(H2O)4]^+ + H2O}$$

as well as

$$\ce{[Fe(SCN)2(H2O)4]^+ + SCN^- <=> [Fe(SCN)3(H2O)3] + H2O}$$

which each can be described by an individual thermodynamic constant $K$.

Third, *tetrahedral complex* refers to a cation in the centre with four bonds extending to ligands.  Neither the simplified description of $\ce{[Fe(SCN)3]}$, nor the better one of $\ce{[Fe(SCN)3(H2O)3]}$ fits this well.  (Here, both water and $\ce{SCN^-}$ are monodentate ligands. So the number of ligands equates to the number of «bonds» between the ligands and the central metal cation.)  A typical shape of complexes of formula $\ce{MA3B3}$ (with both $\ce{A}$ and $\ce{B}$ monodentates) is the octahedral one.

Comment: Oh got it, but just to make it clear I am a first year college student and this is my first chemistry course, and this was one of the previous year question of this course, and we barely even covered tetrahedral geometry, so like about the color change is it that that as ligands are changing the value of $\Delta$ changes, that is why there is a change in color?

Comment: @KutubkhanBhatiya How the MOs split (which are the orbitals lower, or higher in energy, relative to each other; the split of the ligand field to be square quadratic, tetrahedral, cubic, octahedral; how large is the energy gap between MOs) depends on the ligands, their number of bonds (monodentate/chelating ligand; hapticity of the central cation); initial electron configuration of the cation. For $\ce{ML6}$ complexes, depending if additional electrons «enter» orbitals antiparallel in spin to already present electrons, there are low-spin/high spin complexes. It certainly takes time to learn it.

Comment: Hey @Buttonwood you seem pretty good, maybe you can attempt my question here https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/172258/colored-inorganic-liquids-why-is-scl2-red-and-s2cl2-orange

Comment: @NealConroy I speculate someone deeply invested in quantum chemistry could provide an estimate which electronic transitions should be considered for $\ce{SCl2}$ and $\ce{S2Cl2}$, but it isn't me.