How does Huckel's model, particles in a box, etc., explain the color of polyacenes?
Basically looking into what is the crystal field theory, and ligand theory, of organic compounds, such as for these polyacenes.
Also naphthalene is also a white powder, so going from 2-benzene to 3-benzene does not change color, but does going from 3-benzene to 4-benzene and etc.


It's not "crystal field theory of organic compounds" 2) Color changes, but initially in UV region.


https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodward%27s_rules

You should really try to use the Hückel method to compute the energy level differences and the wave/matter duality relations to derive the wavelength associated with a transition. (It's a really crude approximation but it usually works for simple molecules). You could even use 2D boxes infinite well potentials to derive the $\Delta E$ associated with a transition.

@GiuseppeBasile what computer program do I use?

use pen and paper for the particle in a box, while for Huckel method use pen and paper till you get the secular determinant and then maybe use matlab to solve the determinantal equation.

@GiuseppeBasile okay, are Woodward's rules still valid?

those rules are empirical, meaning that they come from observations and do not make use, in principle, of any theoretically sound argument. They should work fine, but toy models and Huckel method could give you a deeper understanding of the problem

@GiuseppeBasile so the particle in a box, and secular determinant, could also be used for inorganic compounds like Cl-S-Cl?

Not even in the slightest. Did you take any course in physical chemistry or inorganic chemistry?

The problem is that those models work under certain assumptions, that you need to carefully understand: particle in a 2D box works just because the molecules you  cited are almost perfectly planar with delocalized electrons over and under the plane where the rings lie

Huckel method needs similar assumptions to work on aromatic compounds and conjugated systems

@GiuseppeBasile oh okay, people told me about making quantum chemistry calculations for Cl-S-Cl in my other thread, on why is it red https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/172258/colored-inorganic-liquids-why-is-scl2-red-and-s2cl2-orange

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@GiuseppeBasile here's the thing, yes I can do all the particle-in-the-box calculations and get the transitions or wavelength in nm, and then get the color. But thing is we already know what the colors are. My question is more of why the patterns are, as we increase the amount of benzene rings. From white to orange to black...

Well, you can get a simple answer to that, for the particle in a box: plot the energy as a function of L_x, L_y and you will get a certain dependency, this is a crude approximation for what you want (also do not  extend conversations that ar moved to chat, please)

@GiuseppeBasile yea, I wanted to reserve the chat for the particles-in-a-box calculation. I generally find the particles-in-a-box for trying to predict the colors of something that has never been synthesized, for example. How does the particle-in-a-box work for compounds that don't exist, i.e., compounds that exist for milliseconds, does it still return a color, or does it reach some mathematical inconsistency (like dividing by 0).
